# Maximum number of classes, visualforce pages and page layouts per saleforce org?

Tags: apex, visualforce, limits

Is there and if so, what is the maximum number of classes, visualforce pages and page layouts that can be created per salesforce organization?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no limit for VisualForce Pages but the Maximum number of class and trigger code units in a deployment of Apex is 5000. You can get all the limits [here](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/204/17/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf).

Salesforce [recommends](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=layouts_tips.htm&language=de_2_3_2_3&type=0) creating no more than 200 page layouts. Although there is no limit, it can be difficult to manage your page layouts if you have more than 200.

Comment: I think I accidentally edited your answer instead of posting a new one. I apologize for that. I have reverted that

Comment: Thanks @Saroj Bera...is there limits for visual force pages too?

Comment: I could not find the limit, but you would probably hit other limits first like 3 MB of apex code limit and 5000 classes.

Answer (score 2):

There is a limit of 3MB/3 million characters on classes and triggers combined excluding test classes and comments.

This limit can be increased by raising a case with Salesforce Support depending on type of edition you have.

Each class cannot have more than a million characters.

There is no limit on page layouts or VF pages. However large number of layouts and pages will be difficult to manage.

**Update:**

The code limit is doubled in [Summer 18](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_apex_code_size_limit.htm?edition=&impact=) to 6 million characters.